# how can i set window size that button remain same whether window size maximize or not?

Tags: wpf, size, wpfdatagrid

i have approx 20 buttons in wpf application. now when the window size is small all is looking good but whenever i maximize the size of the window.The window size increases but they all remain on their position and its look awkward.

```
<Window x:Class="LINQ.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Linq Queries" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,29,0,0">


        <DataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,55,0,0"/>
        <Button Content="Query1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,-27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? Enlarge buttons, block maximizing of window or something else?

Comment: what i want is that when window size is enlarged my button will also enlarged according to that window size

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use `Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`. Sample code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5"
            Content="Button 1" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5"
            Content="Button 2" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5"
            Content="Button 3" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5"
            Content="Button 4" />
</Grid>
```